# .groupby .agg does not work as expected in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My dataframe is like:

[image]

I used the following code to calculate the sum, mean and std of a column for each group, but it gave me an error.

```
New11.groupby(level=0)['Population'].agg([np.sum,np.mean,np.std])
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

However, the following code worked fine.

```
New11.groupby(level=0)['Population'].agg([np.sum])
```

This code gives an error.

```
New11.groupby(level=0)['Population'].agg([np.average])
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

How should I modify my code to make it work?

Comment: Try New11.groupby(New11.index)['Population'].agg(['sum', 'mean', 'std'])

Comment: It gives an error.  DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: Check the column data type: New11.dtypes... Assuming it is an "Object" use pd.to_numeric(New11['Population']). Then try the above

Answer (score 0):

Please try convert the values of 'Population' in float32 of the next form `New11['Population]=np.float32(New11['Population'])`. You can check this in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try

`New11.groupby(level=0).agg({'Population': ['sum', 'mean', 'std']})`